# Highlight current UICollectionViewCell tvOS

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, tvos

I'm currently developing an app as a proof of concept for the appleTV. And I'm trying to show a queue. Which is separated in different departments. We've got Mac, iPhone, iPad... And I'd like to update my collectionView automatically to show which departement is showing.

I've already succeeded to update my tableview automatically.

Is there something don't see?

[image]

And here is the code of my controller

```
class QueueViewController : UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
var departments = [Department]()
var users = [User]()
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    print("QueueViewController")
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "BackgroundQueue")!)
    fetchDepartments()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
}
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    //Hier moet de fetch task worden uitgevoerd
    if departments.count > 0 {
        startTimer()
    }
}
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    stopTimer()
}
//MARK: - CollectionView
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return departments.count
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DepartmentItemCell
    let department = departments[indexPath.row]
    let title = department.name
    cell.DepartmentButton.setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)
    cell.DepartmentButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    cell.DepartmentButton.restorationIdentifier = department.id
    return cell

}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("indexpath :\(indexPath.row)")
}

@IBAction func selectDepartment(sender: AnyObject) {
    fetchQueueForDepartment(sender.restorationIdentifier!!)
}

//MARK: - TableView
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return users.count
}
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableCell") as! QueueItemCell
    let user = users[indexPath.row]

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let attributes = [
            NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : 1]
        let title = NSAttributedString(string: "\(user.firstname!) \(user.lastname!)", attributes: attributes) //1
        cell.nameLabel.attributedText = title
        return cell

    }

    cell.nameLabel.text = "\(user.firstname!) \(user.lastname!)"
    cell.arrivalLabel.text = user.arrivalDate == nil ? "" : dateFormatter.stringFromDate(user.arrivalDate!)

 return cell
}

//MARK: - Focus update
override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    super.didUpdateFocusInContext(context, withAnimationCoordinator: coordinator)


}
//Zorgt ervoor dat je de cellen in collectionview kan selecteren. focus op zetten
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, canFocusItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool
{
    return false
}

//MARK: - Parse
func fetchDepartments(){
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    ParseService.sharedInstance.fetchDepartments({
        (error, data) -> () in
        if let json_data = data?["result"] {
            self.departments = DepartmentHandler.parseJson(json_data!)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                () -> Void in
                print("succeed")
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                //Eerste departement
                self.fetchQueueForDepartment(self.departments[0].id!)
                self.startTimer()

            })
        }
    })
}

func fetchQueueForDepartment(identifier: String){
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    ParseService.sharedInstance.fetchUsersPerDepartment(identifier,completion:{
        (error, data) -> () in
        if let json_data = data?["result"] {
            self.users = UserHandler.parseJSon(json_data!)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                () -> Void in
                print("succeed")
                self.tableView.reloadData()

                //self.updateFocusCell()
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            })
        }
    })

}


//-----------------------------------------------
//For the loop
var timer: dispatch_source_t!
var item = 0
//MARK: - Loop fetch
func startTimer() {

    let queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.icapps.caps", nil)
    timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue)
    dispatch_source_set_timer(timer, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 10 * NSEC_PER_SEC, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC) // every 10 seconds, with leeway of 1 second
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer) {
        // do whatever you want here
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: self.item, inSection: 0)
        self.fetchQueueForDepartment(self.departments[indexPath.row].id!)

        self.collectionView.selectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .None)



        print(self.item)
        print(self.departments[indexPath.row].name!)

        self.item++
        if self.item == self.departments.count {
            self.item = 0
        }

    }
    dispatch_resume(timer)

}

func stopTimer() {
    if timer != nil {
        print("Stop")
        dispatch_source_cancel(timer)
        timer = nil
    }

}
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use collectionview Delegate method, method name is

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didUpdateFocusInContext context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) 
{
}
```

You can use this method like this...

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didUpdateFocusInContext context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {

    if let previousIndexPath = context.previouslyFocusedIndexPath,
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(previousIndexPath) {
        cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
        cell.contentView.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
        cell.contentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0
    }

    if let indexPath = context.nextFocusedIndexPath,
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
        cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 8.0
        cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        cell.contentView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        cell.contentView.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
        cell.contentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9
        cell.contentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: [.CenteredHorizontally, .CenteredVertically], animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didUpdateFocusIn context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    if let pindex  = context.previouslyFocusedIndexPath, let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: pindex) {
        cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
        cell.contentView.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
        cell.contentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
    }

    if let index  = context.nextFocusedIndexPath, let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: index) {
        cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 8.0
        cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        cell.contentView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        cell.contentView.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
        cell.contentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.9
        cell.contentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: index, at: [.centeredHorizontally, .centeredVertically], animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unspecific but if i understood it correctly you want to manually highlight a collection view cell instead if letting the tvOS focus handle it automatically?

If thats so I believe you need to look at this delegate method which I couldn't see in your viewController

```
 - collectionView:shouldUpdateFocusInContext:
```

As per apples documents this delegate does the following

Discussion
The functionality of this delegate method is equivalent to overriding the UICollectionView class’s collectionView:shouldUpdateFocusInContext: method. However, this delegate method provides additional UICollectionView-related information in its context parameter, such as the index paths for the previously and next focused views. These index paths are only available if their views are contained within the collection view.

So you should use this delegate method to override the current focus and than select a new cell to focus manually.

Also why does your canFocusItemAtIndexPath return false?

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll try it immediately. And I've had to set my 'canFocusItemAtiIndexPath' on false because otherwise I couldn't select it with my controller

Comment: No problem, I am still fairly new to tvOS as well so I am not 100% sure. There are other properties you can check out, not sure if they apply to your situation, like  "preferredFocusedView" and "setNeedsFocusUpdate". https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/WorkingwiththeAppleTVRemote.html

Comment: It didn't help but I'm searching on another solution. And I've already read the part of airbnb but thanks!

Comment: no problem, post an answer if you find one. I just started using CollectionViews as well so beyond the basic focus stuff I dont know much either.

Comment: Found a solution: 
 func indexPathForPreferredFocusedViewInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> NSIndexPath? {
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: self.item, inSection: 0)
        return indexPath
    }

This made sure my index path is focussed

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented following method which made sure my preferred view is updated

```
func indexPathForPreferredFocusedViewInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> NSIndexPath? {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: self.item, inSection: 0)
    return indexPath
}
```

Comment: Great, I was close hahah

Comment: This method is bugged https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48585956/indexpathforpreferredfocusedview-is-not-being-called